# Relacion de alumno con sus notas en los cursos

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas

Saludo a todos, tengo problemas al intentar relacionar unas tablas en un proyecto de una plataforma escolar.

Actualmente tengo una tabla alumno, una tabla curso(que esta relacionada con una tabla clase), una tabla confNota que la utilizo para personalizar las notas(Examen parcial, examen final, tareas, etc) y una tabla NotaParcial la que almacena las subnotas(tarea1, tarea2, tarea3, etc.).

Mi problema inicia al intentar relacionar estas tablas para que el profesor pueda registrar las notas de los alumnos, he intentado crear una tabla detalleCurso pero llegado un punto no encuentro la forma de relacionar una nota con el alumno y con el curso. Espero puedan darme alguna idea de como solucionarlo. Adjunto un diagrama referencial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué tal una tabla "CursoAlumnoNota"que relacione IDCurso, IDAlumno y Nota?

Comment: Amigo en la la tabla alumnos creas un campo que se llame id_curso, para saber a que curso pertenece cada alumno, luego creas otra tabla para guardar el Id de la nota y el Id del alumno

Comment: Estoy en desacuerdo. Lo que propones es que un alumno puede estar en sólo un curso en cualquier momento. Debe haber una tabla AlumnoCurso porque es una relación de muchos a muchos. Un alumno puede estar en muchos cursos y un curso puede tener muchos alumnos.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon amigo.